# My custom service provider doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a custom service provider in my app called `DemoServiceProvider` in `app/providers` directory , and i register it in `config/app` as `App\Providers\DemoServiceProvider::class`

here is my `DemoServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class DemoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    dd("test");
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
        //
}
}
```

the problem is i don't see **"test"** ,did i miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution ,it was with these two commands `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan cache:clear` .

Comment: not work for me. i have my code in an package, never provider in package folder work, only app/providers folder

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code and I retrieve:

```
php artisan serve --port=4433
"test"
```

Have you tried already:

```
composer dumpautoload
php artisan cache:clear
```